# Keep app from being added to dock

Tags: catalina, dock, administrator

I am running MacOS 10.15.7. Corp IT has an app that, after being removed from the dock keeps getting added back. I don't mind the app itself, just don't need to have my dock cluttered. I do have admin rights on the machine, so I should be able to change the permissions in the location where this is happening, just don't know where that is.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356591/how-do-i-prevent-icons-from-being-added-to-the-dock?rq=1) or [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361543/macos-app-icon-remaining-in-dock-even-after-closing-app?rq=1) help.

Comment: I did see the first one and while it's a very similar scenario, the OP does not say anything about having admin rights (it's also from 3 years ago).

Comment: [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414239/moving-macos-mail-app-icon-from-dock-to-the-menu-bar) mentions [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar)

Comment: @Barmar this could be a great alternate solution, but I was hoping for a free one.